# how to use glob.glob() and glob.iglob() recursively in python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, glob

I am using the below code to get the file path:

```
import glob
def get_filepath():
    return glob.glob('Users' + '/**/' + 'com.google.Chrome.plist', recursive = True)

print(get_filepath())
```

In `python3`, I get the desired output:

`['/Users/Shared/adi/com.google.Chrome.plist', '/Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist']`

But as the `Recursive = True`  is not a valid argument for `glob.glob()` in `Python2`, I get `unexpected keyword argument` error.

But the script in which I'm using the above code, needs to be backward compatible with `python2` as well.

I tried this code for `Python2`:

```
import glob
def get_filepath():
    return glob.glob('Users' + '/**/' + 'com.google.Chrome.plist')

print(get_filepath())
```

But it gives me:
`[]`

1. How can I rewrite the code so that its compatible both in `Python2` and `Python3` and recursively as well ?
2. Please help extending the same example for `glob.iglob()` as well ?

Comment: Did you look at os.walk ?

Comment: I did. But some articles say, os.walk will be slower than glob.glob(). Also my system being MAC, I am more familiar with linux like wild card match